# MongoDB $lookup with _id as a foreignField in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I am beating my head on the table for too long with this one...

I have two MongoDB collections: "chatroom" and "users". The "chatroom" collection has "user_id" key pointing to a specific single user in "users" collection.

I am trying to fetch the chatroom with a user using the $lookup aggregate query, what I currently have is this one:

```
$this->mongo->chatroom->aggregate(
    array('$lookup' => array(
        'from' => 'users',
        'localField' => 'user_id',
        'foreignField' => '_id',
        'as' => 'user'
    ))
);
```

However, this returns an empty "user" field in the collection. The weird thing is that if I try to replace the "_id" with custom "uid" set to the value of _id.$id, it works as expected:

```
$this->mongo->chatroom->aggregate(
    array('$lookup' => array(
        'from' => 'users',
        'localField' => 'user_id',
        'foreignField' => 'uid', // uid = _id.$id
        'as' => 'user'
    ))
);
```

I figured out the problem is that "_id" is ObjectId while "user_id" is a String. But I don't know how to deal with the problem nicely...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question, I went around the problem by making "user_id" an instance of a "MongoId" class instead of a plain string. Basically, I store "user_id" as:

```
$mongoObject["user_id"] = new MongoId($this->user_id);
```

Another solution would probably be decorating the objects with "uid" field with a value equal to "_id.$id".

Comment: It's actually not *"..going around the problem"(sic)* at all, but "correcting" the problem. Just like issuing **any** query, the data must be of the same "type" to match. So the `"localField"` and `"foreignField"` must both have the same BSON type or the subsequent "query" fails. Just as if you tried to query your `users` collection with an `_id` supplied as a string and not re-cast, then that query would return no results. No difference, and by design.

Comment: Yes, I get this and agree this is a correct behavior - just got a bit confused since I couldn't find any way to do the conversion in aggregate query and visual tool didn't tell me the type (just displayed value as a string).

Comment: You cannot "re-cast" types in aggregate ( there are some funny exceptions to that, but it's the general rule  ) or at least not for `ObjectId`. The correct thing to do is acutally change both types to be the same so they indeed "match". Also always use the `mongo` shell to inspect data. It may lack "bells and whistles", but it's the one thing "guaranteed" to show you the correct types. It is an official product, so that should be expected. Accept your own answer. It's the correct approach.